# delphi 7 timer reset

Tags: delphi, timer

How could one reset the TTimer1 so even ontimer triggers, and the count restarted?

The Question is for Design Time command to act on Run-time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose you actually mean that

```
var
  Timer1: TTimer;
```

Then, to reset the timer, do

```
Timer1.Enabled := false;
Timer1.Enabled := true;
```

In my "RejbrandCommon.pas" standard library, I have actually defined

```
procedure RestartTimer(Timer: TTimer);
begin
  Timer.Enabled := false;
  Timer.Enabled := true;
end;
```

Then, every time I need to restart I timer, I just do

```
RestartTimer(Timer1);
```

Of course, if you want the `OnTimer` procedure (e.g. `Timer1Timer`) to trigger prior to restart, you have to do

```
Timer1.OnTimer(Self);
Timer1.Enabled := false;
Timer1.Enabled := true;
```

or define

```
procedure TriggerAndRestartTimer(Timer: TTimer);
begin
  Timer.OnTimer(nil);    
  Timer.Enabled := false;
  Timer.Enabled := true;
end;
```

(Of course, the last procedure, `TriggerAndRestartTimer`, is not a method, and hence there is no `Self`. However, most likely the `Timer1Timer` procedure doesn't care about the `Sender` property, so you can send just anything, such as `nil` instead of `Self`.)

Comment: I know it works. Do it all the time. Why doesn't it work? Isn't the timer reset, is the event not fireing, doesn't the code compile, does the computer explode?

Comment: Do I really need to set it to false? If I only set it to true does it not get reset?

Comment: @codeGood: Yes, you need to do that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a correction to Andreas' answer: if you call his RestartTimer on a timer that was disabled, it will (accidentally) enable that timer. So, here is the fix: the ResetTimer procedure.

```
procedure ResetTimer(Timer: TTimer);
VAR OldValue: Boolean;
begin
 OldValue:= Timer.Enabled;
 Timer.Enabled:= FALSE;      { Stop timer }
 Timer.Enabled:= OldValue;   { Start the timer ONLY if was enabled before }
end;
```

or

```
procedure ResetTimer(Timer: TTimer);
begin
 if NOT Timer.Enabled then EXIT;
 Timer.Enabled:= FALSE;      { Stop timer }
 Timer.Enabled:= TRUE;       { Start the timer ONLY if was enabled before }
end;
```

For those who really want to RESTART the timer then Andreas' procedure is just fine.

---

And here is the final/proper answer:

```
UNIT cvTimer;
{----------------------
  Better Timer
------------------------------------}

INTERFACE  {$WARN UNIT_PLATFORM OFF}

USES
   System.Classes, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

TYPE
  TMyTimer= class(TTimer)
  private
  public
    procedure Reset;
  end;

IMPLEMENTATION

procedure TMyTimer.Reset;
begin
 if NOT Enabled then EXIT;
 Enabled:= FALSE;      { Stop timer }
 Enabled:= TRUE;       { Start the timer ONLY if was enabled before }
end;

procedure Register;
begin
 RegisterComponents('3rdParty', [TMyTimer]);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do it in design time. Have the handler disable the `TTimer` then re-enable it.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting a TTimer to re-trigger its event is simple. When you disable and enable the TTimer, your timertimeout event will re-trigger based on its time interval you set. For instance,

```
Timer1.interval:=1000; //milliseconds
Timer1.enabled:=false;
Timer1.enabled:=true;
```

Timer1 event will fire when one second is up the next time you enable and disable the timer.